# Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...t center center": expected "{", was "}.owl-carousel...."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

On my local system this works fine, but on development server when I have updated my code and run `RAILS_ENV=demo rake assets:precompile --trace`, then I get this error:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...t center center": expected "{", was "}.owl-carousel...."
(sass):6767
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1179:in `expected'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1115:in `expected'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1110:in `tok!'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:654:in `block'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:724:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:674:in `block_child'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:666:in `block_contents'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:655:in `block'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:647:in `ruleset'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:673:in `block_child'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:666:in `block_contents'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:123:in `stylesheet'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:39:in `parse'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/engine.rb:403:in `_to_tree'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_directory'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/box-admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@echopractices/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I am using rails 4.2.1, Ruby 2.2.1 and below is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specified version of ruby for this project
ruby '2.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# This will pull in less as a runtime dependency: https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails
gem 'less-rails'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# Use Capistrano for deployment
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.3'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-rails-collection'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'capistrano-rails-console'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  #gem 'spring'

  #pagination
  gem 'will_paginate'

  #mini_magic
  gem "mini_magick"

  #active_admin gem
  gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
  gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
  gem 'devise'

  #paperclip
  gem "paperclip", git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
end
```

In my log file I have an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...t center center": expected "{", was "}.owl-carousel...."):
    59:             <div class="col-md-6">
    60:                <div class="summ-wrapper">
    61:                   <div class="cert-logo">
    62:                      <%= image_tag("cert-logo", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
    63:                   </div>
    64:                   <div class="tag-count">
    65:                       <%= new_val.quantity -%>
  app/views/buy_tags/search_results.html.erb:62:in `block in _app_views_buy_tags_search_results_html_erb__676313959006132478_35621880'
  app/views/buy_tags/search_results.html.erb:39:in `_app_views_buy_tags_search_results_html_erb__676313959006132478_35621880'in
```

search_results.html.erb:

```
<!-- Document Wrapper
============================================= -->
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">

  <!-- Header
  ============================================= -->
  <header id="header" class="full-header">
    <div id="header-wrap">
      <div class="container clearfix">
        <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>
        <!-- Logo
        ============================================= -->
        <div id="logo">
         <a href='/' data-no-turbolink class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="<%= image_path("logo-ecocredits.png") %>">
         <%= image_tag("logo-ecopractices.png", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
          </a>
          <a href='/' data-no-turbolink class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="<%= image_path("logo-ecocredits@2x.png") %>">
            <%= image_tag("logo-ecocredits@2x.png", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
          </a>
        </div><!-- #logo end -->
        <!-- Primary Navigation
        ============================================= -->
        <nav id="primary-menu">
          <ul>
            <li class="how_it_works_load"><%= link_to 'HOW IT WORKS', controller: 'how_it_works' %></li>
            <li class="produce_tag_load"><%= link_to 'PRODUCE ECOTAGS', controller: 'produce_tags' %></li>
            <li class="buy_tag_load current"><%= link_to 'BUY ECOTAGS', controller: 'buy_tags' %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </header><!-- #header end -->


  <!-- Content
  ============================================= -->

<% @producer.each do |new_val| -%>     

  <section id="content">

    <div class="content-wrap">

      <div class="main-banner section parallax dark nobottommargin header-stick notopborder" style="background: url('<%= image_path("show-head.png") %>') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;height: 250px;" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.3">
        <div class="container clearfix">
          <div class="buy-header">
            <h2>ECOTAG CERTIFICATE - #<%= new_val.producer_id -%></h2>
            <p id="up25">This Ecotag is Available for Purchase</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container clearfix">
         <div class="return-search">
            <a href='/buy_tags/index' data-no-turbolink><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> &nbsp;BACK TO SEARCH RESULTS</a>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="summ-wrapper">
                  <div class="cert-logo">
                     <%= image_tag("cert-logo", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tag-count">
                      <%= new_val.quantity -%>
                     <div class="tag-count-title">
                        certified Ecotags
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price">
                     price: <span class="green-text">$<%= new_val.value -%></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="buy-btn">
                   <a href='mailto:jriediger@agsolver.com?subject="Purchase Ecotag#<%= new_val.value.to_i -%>"' data-no-turbolink><%= image_tag("buy-btn", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %></a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="overview">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                     <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                           <th class="black-text">Status</th>
                           <th><span class="green-text">Available</span></th>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="black-text"><strong>State</strong></td>
                           <td class="text-underline state_id" data-href="/buy_tags/index?state=<%= new_val.stateName -%>"><%= new_val.stateName -%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="black-text"><strong>Practice</strong></td>
                           <td class="text-underline sector_id" data-href="/buy_tags/index?sector=<%= new_val.practiceTypeName -%>"><%= new_val.practiceTypeName -%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="black-text"><strong>Impact</strong></td>
                           <td class="text-underline impact_id" data-href="/buy_tags/index?impact=<%= new_val.impact -%>"><%= new_val.impact -%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- This section has been changed 
                        <tr>
                           <td class="black-text"><strong>Nutrient Loss Reductions</strong></td>
                           <td>
                            N Reduction: <strong><%= new_val.nreduction -%></strong><br />
                            P Reduction: <strong><%= new_val.preduction -%></strong>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        -->
                     </table>
                     <br />
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <th style="color: #000;">Practice Change Details</th>
                      </thead>
                    </table>
                    <table class="table new-table" style="margin-top:-10px;">
                      <thead>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>Min</th>
                        <th>Max</th>
                        <th>Avg</th>
                        <th>NH4</th>
                        <th>NO3</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="color: #000;"><strong>N reduction</strong></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td><%= new_val.nreduction -%></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                      </tr>
                      <thead>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>Min</th>
                        <th>Max</th>
                        <th>Avg</th>
                        <th>NH4</th>
                        <th>NO3</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="color: #000;"><strong>P reduction</strong></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td><%= new_val.preduction -%></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section parallax dark" style="background: url('<%= image_path("data-bg.png") %>') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;height: 650px;" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.3">
        <div class="container clearfix">
          <div class="buy-header">
          <h2 style="font-size: 34px;"><span class="green-text">WHAT DOES THIS OFFSET?</span></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="pad-50-left">
                  <%= image_tag("car-icon", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
                  <br />
                  <div class="stats">
                     2,400
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div id="invest-divider"></div>
                  <div class="small-stats">
                     car emissions offset
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="pad-50-left">
                  <%= image_tag("food-icon", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
                  <br />
                  <div class="stats">
                     500
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div id="invest-divider"></div>
                  <div class="small-stats">
                     more people fed per day
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="pad-50-left">
                  <%= image_tag("cloud-icon", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
                  <br />
                  <div class="stats">
                     56,000
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div id="invest-divider"></div>
                  <div class="small-stats">
                     kg if co<sup>2</sup> reduced
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="pad-50-left">
                  <%= image_tag("people-icon", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
                  <br />
                  <div class="stats" style="margin-left:1px;">
                  6<span style="font-size:26px; margin-top:-40px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div id="invest-divider"></div>
                  <div class="small-stats">
                     months of avg. life expectancy
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container clearfix">
         <h2 style="font-size: 34px;"><span class="green-text">WHAT ARE THE DIRECT EFFECTS</span></h2>
         <div id="invest-divider" style="border-color:#00b033;"></div>
         <br />
         <br />
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 field-img">
              <div class="land-stats-container">
                  <% if new_val.image %>
                      <% name = new_val.producer_id + '.PNG' %>
                     <%= image_tag(name, {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
                  <% else %>
                     <%= image_tag("field", {:class=>"img-responsive"}) %>
                  <% end %>
                  <div class="land-stats-a">
                     acres: <span class="green-text"><%= new_val.acres -%></span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="land-stats-e">
                     Ecotags: <span class="green-text"><%= new_val.quantity -%></span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
               <p class="font22">This Ecotag directly offsets the eco-friendly practices of a specific food producer and helps to supplement the costs if the following good practices for sustainability:
               <br />
               <hr style="border-color:#888;">
               <div class="accordion-wrapper">
                  <div class="accordion-header1">
                     <span class="green-text arrow-down" style="font-size:30px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
                     <span class="green-text arrow-up" style="font-size:30px;display:none;"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>
                     <span class="pad-25-left"><%= new_val.practiceTypeName -%></span> 
                     <span style="padding-left:15px; color:#999; font-size:30px;"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            <hr style="border-color:#888;">
            <div class="accordion-body1">
               <p><%= @content_detail -%>
            </div>               
            <div class="references">
               <div class="ref-header">
                  references
               </div>
               <hr style="border-color:#666;">
               <div class="ref-body">
               <% if @ref_details %>
                  <p><%= @ref_details.html_safe -%></p>
               <% end %>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /.content-wrap -->

  </section> <!-- #content end -->
<% end %>
  <!-- Footer
  ============================================= -->
  <footer id="footer" class="dark">

    <!-- Copyrights
    ============================================= -->
    <div id="copyrights">
      <div class="container clearfix">
        <p class="center">Sustainability Partners &copy; 2016, All Rights Reserved<br></p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- #copyrights end -->

  </footer><!-- #footer end -->
</div><!-- #wrapper end -->

<!-- Go To Top
============================================= -->
<div id="gotoTop" class="icon-angle-up"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".accordion-header1").click(function(){
    $(".accordion-body1").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".arrow-down").toggle();
        $(".arrow-up").toggle();
  });
  $(".accordion-header2").click(function(){
    $(".accordion-body2").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".arrow2").toggleClass("fa.fa-angle-up");
        $(".arrow-down2").toggle();
        $(".arrow-up2").toggle();
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".sector_id").mouseover(function(){
      $(".sector_id").css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    });
    $(".sector_id").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
    $(".state_id").mouseover(function(){
      $(".state_id").css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    });
    $(".state_id").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
    $(".impact_id").mouseover(function(){
      $(".impact_id").css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    });
    $(".impact_id").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".buy_tag_load a, .produce_tag_load a, .how_it_works_load a").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It just sounds like you need to fix the error in your sass file.  Can you include the relevant section of the file in your question please?

Comment: Typos in css never throw error on your local server. It seems you have used  an "{" instead of "} in your file.

Comment: @techdreams I have added the file can you check it again..!! Thanks.

Comment: which is the last and which is the second last file

Comment: @techdreams search_results.html.erb this is the last file

Comment: show line numbers in it and which is the one before it

Comment: post contents of your .sass

Comment: I see a Sass error, but I see everything *except for the Sass code that reproduces that error*.  You need to provide an [MCVE] (emphasis on **minimal**), not every single piece of code tangentially related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make your image_tag to either of these:

`image_tag("cert-logo", :class=>"img-responsive")`

or

`image_tag("cert-logo", class: "img-responsive")`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Let me know if it works.